# SpringBoot far jar descompression and compression

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader, executable-jar

I'm trying to modify a Spring Boot fat jar. I'm decompressing the jar file and also the jar files that are inside in the main file. Then I'm compressing them again and recovering the same structure (as far as I understand) but I get ClassNotFoundErrors while executing the final jar file. If I don't uncompress the libraries inside the main jar and I do the same operation then everything works fine.

I guess Spring Boot is doing some sort of validation that I'm not aware of while loading those jars. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you even doing this? You are probably missing some files...

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve by this , what all steps you are doing and how are you compressing them again ?